# Double wifi connection (lan / internet) Ubuntu Server

Tags: interface, configuration, server, wifi, ubuntu-16.04

I got Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 with two wireless USB adapters.
I would like to connect to two different wifi:

- to my own router with wlan0; to the lan only, just to ssh into the server
- to an enterprise network (802.1x/AES/AES) with wlan1 for internet access

I can establish both connections simultaneously but I don't know how to tell wlan0 to connect to the lan only (and not to the internet).
This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`. With this configuration, both wlan get connected but wlan0 has got internet access and wlan1 shows no internet traffic.

Is there a way to connect wlan0 to my router, with no internet access?

```
# auto wlan0 → for lan connection only (?)
auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.xx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.254
wireless-essid <my_essid>
wireless-mode managed
wpa-driver wext
wpa-conf /home/<my_username>/<my_essid>.psk.conf

# auto wlan1 → for internet connection
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
wireless-mode managed
wpa-ssid WOW FI - FASTWEB
wpa-driver wext
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-proto RSN
wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
wpa-eap PEAP
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-EAP
wpa-identity <my_enterprise_id>
wpa-password <my_enterprise_pw>
wpa-phase2 auth=MSCHAPV2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: delete the gateway address so that wlan0 config is

```
# auto wlan0 → for lan connection only (?)
auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.xx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
wireless-essid <my_essid>
wireless-mode managed
wpa-driver wext
wpa-conf /home/<my_username>/<my_essid>.psk.conf
```